# Why does the ranges library define two names for each view?

Tags: c++, range, c++20

In the ranges library for c++20, all the views have a second version.

For instance, [std::ranges::views::filter](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/ranges/filter_view)

According to cppreference:

> The expression views::filter(E, P) is expression-equivalent to
> filter_view{E, P} for any suitable subexpressions E and P.

We have the actual class, `std::ranges::filter_view`, and then put inside the views namespace we have `std::ranges::views::filter`. Is there any difference between the two, or is it purely a matter of style?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> all the views have a second version

No, they do not.

`filter_view` is a type. `filter` is a *functor*. By calling the `filter` functor, you can create an object of the corresponding `filter_view` type (or near-enough).

But you can also call the `filter` functor with only one parameter: the filtering predicate. The return value from such a call is an object which you can `|` against a range to *also* create a `filter_view` equivalent, as described on the very page you linked to:

```
ints | std::views::filter(even)
```

You can't do that with `filter_view` directly.

So, you can either create a filtering view using common C++ notation: `filter_view(range, predicate)`, or you can do it with a more functional style predicate notation: `range | views::filter(predicate)`.